# No steady-state solutions in a PDE system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given a following PDE system with Neumann condition: $u_{t} - \Delta{u} = f\ $ in $\omega$ ($t > 0$), $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{v}} = \phi$ on the boundary of $\omega$ ($t > 0$), and $u = u_{0}$ at $t = 0$.

Now, assume $f$ and $\phi$ is independent of time, and $\int_{\partial\omega} \phi \ ds$ + $\int_{\omega} f\ dx \neq 0$ (so, no steady-state solutions to this PDE). Determine the large-time behavior of solution of the above system (i.e, describe how $u(t,x)$ behaves where $t\rightarrow \infty$).

**My attempt:** It seems to me that since a steady-state solution doesn't exist, if $u$ is the solution to the PDE system, then $u$ cannot converge to $\overline{u}$ where $\overline{u}$ is the steady-state solution, exponentially fast. But I got stuck from here. Can anyone please help with this problem? Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Physically, there is no steady state because $\int_\Omega u(t,x) dx$ is blowing up (in particular its derivative is a nonzero constant). If you take the derivative of this quantity away from $u_t$, then a steady state exists. So you can describe the solution to your problem as a constant times $t$ plus a process which has a true steady state.

Now prove this. You will need multidimensional integration by parts to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Ian. How do you know $\int_\Omega u(t,x) dx$ is blowing up? I can see that its derivative doesn't depend on $t$, as $f$ is independent of $t$, but I'm not sure why it's blowing up? And can you clarify on the meaning of "take the derivative of this quantity away from $u_{t}$? Finally, I tried but failed to prove the solution as a constant times t + a process, as you demonstrated. But doesn't that mean the large-time behavior of solution is that the solution is going to infinity??

Comment: Let $U(t)=\int_\Omega u(t,x) dx$. Then if you have $v_t = \Delta v + f - \frac{U}{|\Omega|}$ with the same initial condition as $u$, then $v$ has a steady state. Then write $u$ in terms of $v$, using the fact that $U$ is a linear function of $t$.

Comment: Thanks for your further hint. But I wonder where the last term $-\frac{U}{\omega}$ came from? I can write $u$ in terms of $v$, but not in the way you said. Rather, I replaced $U(t)$ by $\int_{\omega} u(t, x)\ dx$, then taking derivative w.r.t $x$ on both sides... Maybe I'm too dumb to see, but can you please help with your proof?

Comment: Gah, I made a small error. Let $U(t)=\int_\Omega u(t,x) dx$ and set $v_t = \Delta v + f - \frac{U_t}{|\Omega|}$. The point is that then $v$ has a constant integral over all of $\Omega$. The division by the volume of $\Omega$ is because when you integrate $U_t$ over $\Omega$ you get an additional factor of the volume of $|\Omega|$; so the two cancel out.

Comment: Ok, but how do you get $u$ in terms of $v$? And would we end up with the same form as above, namely $u$ = constant times t + steady-state solution of some processes? So the large-time behavior of $u$ is $u$ would blow up?

Comment: By linearity, $u=v+ct $ for a constant $c $ depending on $f $ and $\phi $.

Comment: thank you so much!! So $u$ really blows up as $t\rightarrow \infty$. Am I right?

Comment: @user177196 That's right.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Ian!! Can you please give this problem a try: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422794/non-existence-of-solution-in-finite-time?