# Non-Existence of solution in finite time

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given $x_{t} - \triangle{x} = x^5$ in a bounded domain $\omega\subset R^n$, with $x=0$ on $\partial \omega$ and $x(s,0)= x_{0}(s)$. Prove that if $E[x_{0}] = \int_{\omega} (\frac{1}{2}|\bigtriangledown{x_0}|^2 - \frac{1}{6} {x_{0}}^6)dx < 0$, then the classical solution doesn't exist in finite time.

**My attempt:** I tried to show that $\frac{d}{dt} E[x(t)]\leq 0$, and then bound $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\omega} x^2\ ds$ by some constants times $E[x(t)]$. But then I failed at proving either of these:( Can somebody please give this problem a try? Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}E[x(t)]= - \int_{\omega}x_t^2 ds  \le 0 $. This is obtained by integration by part (green's identity) and then substitute the given boundary condition and PDE.

Comment: @mastrok: Thank you very much for your help. Can you kindly show your full calculation for that, as I only get this: $\frac{d}{dt} E[x(t)] = \int_{\omega} x'(t)x''(t) - {(x(t))^5}x'(t) =  \int_{\omega} 2x'(t)x''(t)-(x'(t))^2 = \frac{d}{dt}\int_{\omega} {(x'(t))}^2 -  \int_{\omega} {(x'(t))}^2$ (as $(x(t))^5 = x'(t) - x''(t)$, which is NOT obviously $\leq 0$? And did you figure out how would we be able to bound $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\omega} x^2 ds$ by $E[x(t)] using the result we just proved?

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this problem? I really got stuck on how to solve it:(

Comment: Wait, what is your definition of $E[x(t)]$ ? I think your $\Delta$ means laplacian and $x_t$ means $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}x$ ?

Comment: E[x(t)] is actually an integral of function $x(t,s)$.. I think you're correct. I messed up on the above:( Can you show your derivation?

Comment: $E[x(t)] =\int (\frac{1}{2}|\nabla x|^2 -\frac{1}{6} x^6 )ds $ ?

Comment: @mastrok: that's right! If I can show $\frac{d}{dt} E[x(t)]\leq 0$, then I can obtain $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\omega} x^2 ds = -E[x(t)] + \int_{\omega} \frac{4}{3} (x(s,t))^6 ds$, where $-E[x(t)]$ is an increasing function in $t$ with minimum value $> 0$ (due to the fact that $-E[x(0)] > 0$ by assumption). Thus  $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\omega} x^2 ds > 0$, which implies $ \int_{\omega} x^2 ds$ is a STRICTLY increasing function in $t$, so it definitely blows up as $t\rightarrow \infty$, which implies $x^2$ also blows up as  $t\rightarrow \infty$. How to show $x^2$ would blow up at a FINITE time?

Comment: Actually, a stronger result is that $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\omega} x^2 ds > \frac{4}{3} \int_{\omega} x^{2}x^{4}ds$. By using Gronwall's inequality, we can get: $\int_{\omega} x^2 ds > \frac{1}{x^{-2}(0)} - 2Ct$ for some constants $C$. Thus the LHS would blow up at a finite time $t = x^{-2}(0)/2C$, so does $x^2$. Is this proof correct?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}E[x(t)]=\int(\nabla x\cdot \nabla x_t− x^5 x_t)ds =\int(-x_t \Delta x −  x^5 x_t) = -\int(x_t ^2) ds \le 0$

Comment: @mastrok: thank you so much for your help. Why $\bigtriangledown x = -x_{t}$ rather than $x_(t)$? The sign of this term is what really bothered me.

Comment: Be careful here, it is **not** $\nabla x = -x_t$, but $\int(\nabla x_t\cdot \nabla x + x_t \Delta x)ds = \oint x\nabla x_t \cdot d\vec{S} =0  $ which is the Green's identity

Comment: @mastrok: Great!! I finally got it. Thanks a lot for your patience. Can you help check if my other steps in my 8th mini-post above, especially when using Gronwall's inequality, is correct? Were you able to prove the conclusion?